# Keeping previous versions of entities with NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm trying to enable my application to keep previous versions of entities.

For example, if I have a `Book` I want to be able to retrieve it at version 1, or at version 5, etc...

```
public class Book
{
    public virtual int ID {get; set;}
    public virtual string Name {get; set;}
    public virtual int Version {get; set;}
}
```

I map the version column like this:

```
Version(x=>x.Version);
```

This is working. When it's inserted, the version is 1.
If I pull back that entity by id, edit it, and save it, the version increments to 2.

My question is, how can I keep previous versions?

I'm suspecting some kind of composite on ID | Version...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Anton Gogolev pointed out - version property/column is not for auditing but for concurrency control.

[NHibernate Envers](https://bitbucket.org/RogerKratz/nhibernate.envers) is a 3rd party auditing lib for NHibernate that might suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The `Version` construct is used for implementing [optimistic concurrency control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control), not for storing previous versions of entities.

To implement full versioning you'll either have to resort to having a separate insert-only `BookRevision` table or use the now-fashionable CQRS/ES.

Comment: I thought this may be the case. Instead of having a separate table (BookRevision) would there be a way of having a Version col in the Book model, and having a composite key on ID | Version?